# Node Express Server Get not getting the first '?' in a query

Tags: node.js, express

I am trying to make a get call to my node server using the following parameters

```
http://localhost:8080/products/?a=13214?b=awedf
```

I am getting the error: Cannot GET /products/?a=13214?b=awedf

When I remove the '?' before the letter 'a', I get the following query:

```
{ b: 'awedf' }
```

I want to be able to add the '?' and get the following query or something similar that gives me the following array:

```
{ a:13214, b: 'awedf' }
```

Here is the code I have:

```
var express = require('express'),
    app = express();

var timeout = 0;

app.use(express.static(__dirname, '/'));

app.get('/products/:siteId', function(req, res) {
    console.log(req.query);
    res.json(products);
});

app.listen(8080);

console.log('Express listening on http://localhost:8080/');

  var products = [
      {"Product":"Product A"}
      ,{"Product":"Product B"}
  ];
```

EDIT:
I fixed it by changing the query parameters:

```
http://localhost:8080/product?a=13214&b=awedf
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of second `?` add `&`. Parameters are separated with ampersand. Question mark indicates the beginning of query string

Also you don't need `:siteId` in the path. If you want to use `:siteId`, then your url would look like /products/1234?b=abc

req.**params**.siteId === 1234 and `req.query.b === 'abc'`

Answer (score 1):

So you should replace the `?` before `b` with `&` like this: `http://localhost:8080/products/?a=13214&b=awedf`

EDIT: Since you cannot modify the parameters and you already have `/:siteId` then you should be able to access the value for `a` like this: `req.params.siteId`.